# linux 64 swap not empty, OOM kills application

Tags: linux, memory, oom

I getting problem with OOM kills application even with a lot of swap

```
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248706] Free swap  = 3997348kB
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248708] Total swap = 4194300kB
```

I have read [linux not using swap, but OOM killer is triggered](https://superuser.com/questions/891301/linux-not-using-swap-but-oom-killer-is-triggered) and tested that my system allows to allocate more then 4gb by executing

```
stress --vm 1 --vm-bytes 4096M --timeout 10s
```

So what could be the reason of OOM?

```
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248287] lxcfs invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x26000c0, order=2, oom_score_adj=0
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248295] lxcfs cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248334] CPU: 0 PID: 9532 Comm: lxcfs Not tainted 4.4.0-59-generic #80-Ubuntu
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248337] Hardware name: DigitalOcean Droplet, BIOS 20161103 11/03/2016
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248340]  0000000000000286 0000000061807b60 ffff88001be53af0 ffffffff813f7583
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248348]  ffff88001be53cc8 ffff88001d247000 ffff88001be53b60 ffffffff8120ad5e
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248352]  ffffffff81cd2dc7 0000000000000000 ffffffff81e67760 0000000000000206
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248356] Call Trace:
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248424]  [<ffffffff813f7583>] dump_stack+0x63/0x90
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248455]  [<ffffffff8120ad5e>] dump_header+0x5a/0x1c5
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248474]  [<ffffffff81192722>] oom_kill_process+0x202/0x3c0
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248477]  [<ffffffff81192b49>] out_of_memory+0x219/0x460
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248487]  [<ffffffff81198abd>] __alloc_pages_slowpath.constprop.88+0x8fd/0xa70
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248492]  [<ffffffff81198eb6>] __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x286/0x2a0
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248496]  [<ffffffff81198f6b>] alloc_kmem_pages_node+0x4b/0xc0
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248517]  [<ffffffff8107ea5e>] copy_process+0x1be/0x1b70
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248536]  [<ffffffff811c1db1>] ? handle_mm_fault+0x1421/0x1820
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248540]  [<ffffffff810805a0>] _do_fork+0x80/0x360
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248544]  [<ffffffff81080929>] SyS_clone+0x19/0x20
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248575]  [<ffffffff818384f2>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x16/0x71
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248579] Mem-Info:
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248592] active_anon:37699 inactive_anon:38637 isolated_anon:0
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248592]  active_file:12790 inactive_file:10954 isolated_file:0
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248592]  unevictable:914 dirty:933 writeback:0 unstable:0
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248592]  slab_reclaimable:11345 slab_unreclaimable:3766
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248592]  mapped:15752 shmem:6941 pagetables:1685 bounce:0
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248592]  free:2974 free_pcp:0 free_cma:0
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248601] Node 0 DMA free:2052kB min:88kB low:108kB high:132kB active_anon:3096kB inactive_anon:3844kB active_file:1736kB inactive_file:1496kB unevictable:164kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:15992kB managed:15908kB mlocked:164kB dirty:40kB writeback:0kB mapped:3120kB shmem:828kB slab_reclaimable:2300kB slab_unreclaimable:432kB kernel_stack:176kB pagetables:172kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? no
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248615] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 455 455 455 455
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248635] Node 0 DMA32 free:9844kB min:2684kB low:3352kB high:4024kB active_anon:147700kB inactive_anon:150704kB active_file:49424kB inactive_file:42320kB unevictable:3492kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:507896kB managed:484228kB mlocked:3492kB dirty:3692kB writeback:0kB mapped:59888kB shmem:26936kB slab_reclaimable:43080kB slab_unreclaimable:14632kB kernel_stack:4048kB pagetables:6568kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? no
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248646] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0 0
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248651] Node 0 DMA: 339*4kB (UME) 87*8kB (UME) 0*16kB 0*32kB 0*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 2052kB
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248668] Node 0 DMA32: 2065*4kB (UMEH) 121*8kB (UMEH) 8*16kB (H) 2*32kB (H) 1*64kB (H) 1*128kB (H) 1*256kB (H) 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 9868kB
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248695] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=1048576kB
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248697] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248699] 34679 total pagecache pages
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248702] 3393 pages in swap cache
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248704] Swap cache stats: add 3146727, delete 3143334, find 1829619/2085514
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248706] Free swap  = 3997348kB
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248708] Total swap = 4194300kB
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248710] 130972 pages RAM
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248711] 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248713] 5938 pages reserved
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248715] 0 pages cma reserved
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248716] 0 pages hwpoisoned
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248718] [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss nr_ptes nr_pmds swapents oom_score_adj name
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248742] [  666]     0   666     9072      524      21       3      586             0 systemd-journal
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248748] [  709]     0   709    25742      399      19       3       15             0 lvmetad
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248760] [  750]     0   750    10626      355      22       3      221         -1000 systemd-udevd
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248765] [  823]   100   823    25081      321      19       3       64             0 systemd-timesyn
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248770] [ 1646]     0  1646     1306        8       8       3       22             0 iscsid
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248775] [ 1647]     0  1647     1431      877       8       3        0           -17 iscsid
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248779] [ 1652]   104  1652    64099      413      27       3      199             0 rsyslogd
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248783] [ 1653]   107  1653    10726      510      26       4       59          -900 dbus-daemon
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248787] [ 1663] 65534  1663    29630     2839      21       6      192             0 do-agent
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248792] [ 1673]     0  1673    68622      101      36       3       83             0 accounts-daemon
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248796] [ 1676]     0  1676     6511      374      18       3       26             0 atd
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248801] [ 1682]     0  1682     1100      290       8       3       31             0 acpid
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248805] [ 1687]     0  1687     7137      482      19       3       43             0 systemd-logind
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248809] [ 1700]     0  1700     6932      458      18       3       45             0 cron
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248813] [ 1707]     0  1707    67816     3034      27       5      218             0 filebeat
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248817] [ 1710]     0  1710   159019      151      32       4      180             0 lxcfs
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248821] [ 1714]     0  1714   102162     1369      31       5      222             0 topbeat
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248825] [ 1717]     0  1717    51580       43      27       6     1559             0 snapd
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248835] [ 1723]     0  1723    16380      555      35       3      153         -1000 sshd
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248840] [ 1759]     0  1759     9083      474      19       3      112             0 openvpn
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248844] [ 1845]     0  1845    69295      449      38       3       57             0 polkitd
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248848] [ 1847]     0  1847     3665      305      12       3       38             0 agetty
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248852] [ 1851]     0  1851     3619      366      12       3       37             0 agetty
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248856] [ 1900]     0  1900     3344       11      11       3       27             0 mdadm
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248873] [ 1988]     0  1988    22479     1404      48       3       57             0 apache2
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248878] [ 1993]   112  1993    73346      599      69       4      393          -900 postgres
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248882] [ 2062]   112  2062    73379     4431      76       4      410             0 postgres
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248887] [ 2063]   112  2063    73346      296      60       4      411             0 postgres
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248891] [ 2064]   112  2064    73346     1227      61       4      418             0 postgres
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248895] [ 2065]   112  2065    73440      884      64       4      411             0 postgres
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248899] [ 2066]   112  2066    37126      104      57       3      404             0 postgres
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248904] [15573]   113 15573   788794    61244     257       6    35959             0 java
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248909] [15617]   112 15617    74234     5035      77       4      865             0 postgres
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248913] [17217]   112 17217    74302     5378      78       4      613             0 postgres
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248918] [19541]   112 19541    74234     7416      79       4      459             0 postgres
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248923] [22045]     0 22045    12235      617      29       3       11             0 cron
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248927] [22047]     0 22047     1127      168       8       3        0             0 sh
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248931] [22050]     0 22050     1092      363       7       3        0             0 run-parts
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.248936] [22186]    33 22186    94770      951      75       3       51             0 apache2
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.249448] [22187]    33 22187    94770      951      75       3       51             0 apache2
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.249678] [22247]     0 22247     2810      641      11       3        0             0 mlocate
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.249682] [22252]     0 22252     2564       83       9       3        0             0 flock
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.249918] [22253]     0 22253     1523      469       8       3        0             0 updatedb.mlocat
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.249921] Out of memory: Kill process 15573 (java) score 83 or sacrifice child
Jan 21 06:25:19[166423.267860] Killed process 15573 (java) total-vm:3155176kB, anon-rss:238184kB, file-rss:6792kB
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an OOM handling bug in Ubuntu's kernel version 4.4.0-59 that you seem to be using: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1655842. You can either revert to older kernel or download a new fixed kernel that's been posted there.